# How to align images horizontal? (Vuetify.js)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, templates, vuetify.js

What does it look like and what I want:

[image]
My template code:

```
  <v-row>
    <v-col md="6" v-bind:key="el._id" v-for="el in els">
      <v-card max-width="280" tile elevation="0" outlined>{{ text }}</v-card>
        <v-img class="my-10" height="100" width="200" contain :src="src"></v-img>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

I tried everything to every element I found on the internet and in the documentation:

```
class="justify-start" 
align="start"
justify="start"
```

and:

```
style="justify-content: start !important;
  align-content: flex-start !important;
  align-items: flex-start !important;
  align-self: flex-start !important;
  justify-self: flex-start !important;"
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Did you try to add no-gutters to your v-row ?

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: What if you add something like cols="6" to your v-col ?

Comment: @Xanthous Nothing happens then, because `cols="6"` is to me as `md="6"` so it is the same

Comment: Can you add a bit more code from your component to your question ? I see no reason why this wouldn't work, do you have a container or things like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually with the `contain` functionality of Vuetify.
It makes the image as a `background-image` with the `background-position: center center`.
To customized it, in your css you could target the class `.v-image__image--contain` and make it `background-position: left center !important;`.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.v-image__image--contain {
  background-position: left center !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-row>
    <v-col md="6">
      <v-card max-width="280" tile elevation="0" outlined>Test</v-card>
        <v-img class="my-10" height="100" width="200" contain src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" style="background-position: left center;"></v-img>
    </v-col>
    <v-col md="6">
      <v-card max-width="280" tile elevation="0" outlined>Test</v-card>
        <v-img class="my-10" height="100" width="200" contain src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></v-img>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</div>
```